# How to represent the constraint (A && B) || (C && D) || (E && F) ||

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm new to or-tools and I'm trying to represent the constraint:

(!A && !B) || (!C && !D) || (!E && !F) || ...

I tried the following (in my case A is shift_0LM0, B is shift_0LT0, C is shift_0MM0, D is shift_0MT0, ...), expressing !A && !B as A + B == 0, ie. !(A || B):

```
    for week in range(4):
        for employee in range(5):
            model.AddBoolOr([
                shift[f'{week}{weekday}M{employee}'] + shift[f'{week}{weekday}T{employee}'] == 0
                for weekday in 'LMXJVSD'
            ])
```

but I get the error:

`TypeError: NotSupported: model.GetOrMakeBooleanIndex((shift_0LM0 + shift_0LT0) == 0`

is there an easy way to express this constraint?

Comment: you might want to replace `+` sign with a comma (`,`)

Comment: @lenik not sure I follow, AddBoolOr will do an OR with all the constraints received as argument (in a list). `shift_0LM0 + shift_0LT0 == 0` is the first constraint, `shift_0MM0 + shift_0MT0 == 0` is the second constraint, etc. If I change the `+` with a `,` I will get a list of tuples, and a tuple is not a valid constraint.

Comment: AddBoolOr takes a list of Boolean literals (bool_var or bool_var.Not()). You might want to read https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md and https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/boolean_logic.md

Comment: @JoaquinCuencaAbela seems you have already got an explanation, so I'll be brief. "in a list" means line `[a, b]`, not `[a+b]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Laurent said, AddBoolOr expects booleans literals, so you have to create intermediate variables:

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()
a, b, c, d = [model.NewBoolVar(x) for x in 'abcd']

not_a_not_b = model.NewBoolVar('!A && !B')
model.Add(a+b == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(not_a_not_b)

not_c_not_d = model.NewBoolVar('!C && !D')
model.Add(c+d == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(not_c_not_d)

model.AddBoolOr([not_a_not_b, not_c_not_d])

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)

for x in [a, b, c, d]:
    print(solver.Value(x))
```

Edit: for (A && B) || (C && D) just change `a+b == 0` into `a+b == 2`

If you want avoid duplicated solutions when searching for all solutions you have to add the other implication:

```
model.Add(a+b != 0).OnlyEnforceIf(not_a_not_b.Not())
```

Comment: Technically you can get away without intermediate variables (although the cnf grows exponentially). So this shows some (viable) Tseitin-like approach. The thing i wonder about this code: how does ortools treat `model.Add(a+b == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(not_a_not_b)`? Will it be specialized to the boolean space? Assuming, that treating these constraints in the SAT-core (not CP) is best, a natural approach (also doing only implies instead of equality; not sure if better) would be: `model.AddBoolOr([not_a_not_b.Not(), a.Not()])` + `model.AddBoolOr([not_a_not_b.Not(), b.Not()])`. Pure SAT guaranteed.

Comment: Before you posted your answer I tried something similar, having intermediate variables p1 => !A && !B, p2 => !C && !D, ... but when I enumerated all the possible answers I was surprised because I got some duplicated combinations on A, B, C, D. The reason is because you can have !A && !B with p1 true, but also with p1 false. To limit the combinations I had to make p1 <=> !A && !B as explained in https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/boolean_logic.md#product-of-two-boolean-variables. I'll select your solution if you make intermediate vars bijective.